# ListItem.Selected returning true

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I have a `CheckBoxList` and I am looping through all of it's `ListItems`'s and checking if any one of them are checked.

The strange thing is that although only one of them is checked, it thinks ALL of them are checked.

**C# Code:**

```
foreach (ListItem item in cblPermissions.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        // Even though it's not checked on the HTML page - This code still runs.
    }
}
```

This is how I bind the data:

```
private void BindPermissions()
{
    var roles =
        RoleInfoProvider.GetAllRoles(
            string.Format("RoleName like 'EmployerAdmin[_]%' AND SiteID = {0} AND RoleName NOT LIKE '%Super_User%'",
                          CMSContext.CurrentSiteID));

    cblPermissions.DataSource = roles;
    cblPermissions.DataBind();
    var userInfo = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfoByGUID(QueryHelper.GetGuid("guid", Guid.Empty));

    if (userInfo != null)
    {
        var isSuperUser = userInfo.IsInRole(Constants.EmployerAdminSuperUserRole, CMSContext.CurrentSiteName);
        if (!isSuperUser)
        {
            var userRoles = UserInfoProvider.GetUserRoles(userInfo);
            foreach (DataRow row in userRoles.Rows)
            {
                var roleName = row["RoleName"].ToString();
                var roleItem = cblPermissions.Items.FindByValue(roleName);
                if (roleItem != null)
                {
                    roleItem.Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MarkAllPermissionsAsChecked();
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cblPermissions" DataValueField="RoleName" DataTextField="RoleDescription"/>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: How do you bind the data to your CheckBoxList?

Comment: Hi Chris. Please check the update.

Comment: Hi Subby. I have never used kentico before. However, I have used a lot of times the classic controls of asp.net, that are provide by the visual studio, like the CheckBoxList. One thing it seems to me strange is that the bind of the cblCategories's data is done in this handler. Usually, I bind them in the page load event or in an event handler, which should be fired before the data will be binded. I guess repCategories is a control in your html page. What is this for ?

Comment: Oops I pasted the wrong code -_-'. Please check the Update.

Comment: ok np. I will check it right now.

Comment: a possible problem may be the isSuperUser. If this variable is true, then you ckeck all the items of the checkboxlist. So it is reasonable that all of them would be checked.

Comment: Oh my god! I found the problem. One of my checkBox controls had an event which it never suppose to have. The event marked all fo the items in the CBL as true. That explains everything.